# Error Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Object of class Magento\Framework\Phrase could not be converted after upgrade magento version

Tags: products, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5, store-front

Can anyone have faced the below error while opening the product listing page at the storefront?

## After upgrade magento version 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 I am facing.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Object of class Magento\Framework\Phrase could not be converted to int in /home/public_html/website/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml on line 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override **`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml`** in your custom theme.

Then create a file inside your theme **`app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml`**

Add below code to the file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\LocaleFormatter $localeFormatter
 */
?>
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit):?>
                <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_key) ?>"
                    <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif ?>>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(
                        is_numeric($_limit) ? $localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit) : $_limit
                    ) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="limiter-text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('per page')) ?></span>
</div>
```